# How to access parent class variables in child class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

In the child class, how to access the parent class variable?
In the child class method, I want to call the parent class variables.

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class City(Country):
    def __init__(self,city):
        super().__init__()
        self.city=city
        
    def city_info(self):
        print('{}_{}'.format(self.name,self.city))
```

Comment: That _is_ how. But you also need to pass the appropriate values when calling methods on the superclass.

Comment: Your question is not clear. All public attributes of Country is inherited by City automatically. And you can access it using self.the_attribute_name.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding the `__init__` method of the parent class you need to pass all arguments for the super `__init__` method

```py
class Country:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        


class City(Country):
    def __init__(self, name, city):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.city=city
        
    def city_info(self):
        print('{}_{}'.format(self.name,self.city))
```